# Proxy Authentication - Which application is this?

Tags: windows, proxy

I've recently been seeing a window like this:
[image: Proxy Authentication window]

And my problem with this is I'm not using a proxy server, and I can't think of an application that I would have configured to use a proxy, so the window seems a little phishy.

Does someone recognize the program responsible, or know a way i can find out? Taskmgr shows nothing unusual.

Oh yeah, specs: Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64.

Comment: It really looks like a generic popup for a proxy server. You could probably try taking a look at netstat to see if there's anything suspicious, and doublecheck any web enabled software to see if any proxy servers are set for some obscure reason

Comment: Thanks, I'll check netstat the next time this pops up. I checked all my background processes, no proxys set.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Internet options, in the Lan settings, and see if the proxy thing is turned on but has no address?  Control pannel Internet options, Or in IE the "Tools" menu "Internet options", "Connection" tab, and in the "LAN settings".  In there check for the Proxy settings.  There are connection types which may require a setting there, but because you have no entry there, you could test by just turning that off.

It is possible to use this to mess with your computers connection, if it was that switch changing, I would still concider something strange going on.

Comment: The proxy is disabled. I have a setting there for my residental area network, but since I can't set a proxy for a specific network connection and this is a laptop, I rarely enable it.

Comment: what type of accesses brought it up?  did you try disabling Automatic in connections too?

Comment: It appeared when I resumed my laptop from sleep with no programs open. Didn't try disabling automatic proxy setup, will try that next.

Comment: I've disabled the automatic proxy settings, and so far so good, no dialogs since. But it seems interesting that that helped...